# Obtener posición de select option

Tags: java, jsp

Estoy realizando un registro de usuarios en java.jsp, el select option muestra los datos de áreas y roles de la base de datos en String , pero el area y rol se deben registrar con el id.
Mi problema es que al registrar no me deja no se como enviar el valor numerico o posición del select option. 
Mi código es el siguiente.
HTML.

```
 <div class="form-group row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
         <select class="browser-default custom-select">
             <option selected>Areas</option>
             <c:forEach var="areas" items="${areas}">
                 <option  name="area" > ${areas.getArea()} </option>
             </c:forEach>
         </select>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
         <select class="browser-default custom-select">
             <option selected>Roles</option>
             <c:forEach var="rol" items="${roles}">
                 <option  name="rol" >${rol.getRol()} </option>
             </c:forEach>
         </select>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Lógica.

```
String nombres = request.getParameter("txtnombres");
String apellidos = request.getParameter("txtapellidos");
String telefono = request.getParameter("txttelefono");
String correo = request.getParameter("txtcorreo");
String clave = request.getParameter("txtclave");
int area = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("area"));
int rol = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rol"));

us.setNombres(nombres);
us.setApellidos(apellidos);
us.setTelefono(telefono);
us.setCorreo(correo);
us.setClave(clave);
us.setArea(area);
us.setRol(rol);

daouser.AddUsuario(us);

request.getRequestDispatcher("Controlador?menu=Registrar&accion=Listar").forward(request, response);
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Debes usar el atributo value del option
2. Debes usar el atributo id de select

Con lo cual el código te quedaría así:

```
          <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                    <select class="browser-default custom-select" id="area">
                        <option selected>Areas</option>
                        <c:forEach var="areas" items="${areas}">
                            <option  name="area" value="${areas.getId()}" > ${areas.getArea()} </option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <select class="browser-default custom-select" id="rol">
                        <option selected>Roles</option>
                        <c:forEach var="rol" items="${roles}">
                            <option  name="rol" value="${rol.getId()}" >${rol.getRol()} </option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Funciono muchas gracias por tan buena explicación

Comment: Excelente, ahora te pido entonces que le pongas palomita a mi respuesta para que se sepa que la solución funciona y que tu respuesta fue contestada